# Automatically assign number to each string in array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have a large cell array in Matlab (imported from Excel) containing numbers and strings.
Let's say the string part looks like this, just bigger with many columns and lines:

```
Table{1,1} = 'string A'
Table{2,1} = 'string B'
Table{3,1} = 'string B'
```

And the number part looks like this just bigger:

```
Table{1,2} = 5;
Table{2,2} = 10;
Table{3,2} = 15;
```

I am aware that there are disadvantages of working with arrays (right?), so I consider converting EVERYTHING to a numeric matrix by replacing the strings with numbers. (Possibly as a data set with headings - if you don't advise against that?)

My problem is that I have A LOT of different string entries, and I want to automatically assign a number to each entry, e.g. 1 for 'string A', 2 for 'string B' etc., such that:

```
Matrix(1,1) = 1
Matrix(2,1) = 2
Matrix(3,1) = 2
```

etc.

and for the numbers simply:

```
Matrix(1,2) = Table{1,2};
Matrix(2,2) = Table{2,2};
Matrix(3,2) = Table{3,2};
```

For the strings, I cannot assign the numbers by individual code for each string, because there are so many different string entries. Is there a way to "automate" it?

I am aware of this help site, https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/converting-from-string-to-numeric.html, but haven't found anything else helpful.
How would you do it?

Comment: In your post you're converting a cell array of characters to a cell array of double entries. It is still a cell array

Comment: The curly brackets were a typo, I meant to write a matrix of course, sorry! I corrected it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the indices of both numbers and character entries in your cell array using [`isnumeric`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnumeric.html) (or [`ischar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischar.html)) with [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). Then use third output argument of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) (or [`findgroups`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) which requires R2015b) for assigning numbers to character entries of your cell array. Now just put the numbers into your required matrix as shown below:

```
tmp = cellfun(@isnumeric,Table);     %Indices of Numbers
Matrix = zeros(size(Table));         %Initialising the matrix
[~, ~, ic] = unique(Table(~tmp));    %Assigning numbers to characters 
Matrix(~tmp) = ic;                   %Putting numbers for characters
%Above two lines can be replaced with Matrix(~tmp) = findgroups(Table(~tmp)); in R2015b
Matrix(tmp) = [Table{tmp}];          %Putting numbers as they are
```